# How can I set a Projection Matrix to have a Tibia like projection?

Tags: unity-game-engine, opengl, 3d, projection-matrix

I am beating my head a little bit here for a while but I still could bot find a way to set up a matrix that projects my Unity game in a Tibianeske like manner:

[image: example of tibia game view]

Reading on tutorials on internet I could figure out how a normal orthographic perspective works, but tibia's one is kind of odd.

Digging over webs I found in [here](https://opengameart.org/forumtopic/reverse-engineering-ultima-vii-isometrics-wip) a guy (Clint Bellanger) who describes really well how to get the same perspective in blender's render according to him:

> Start with a scene in 45 degree isometric.  Video game style, where
>   the camera angle is Blender (60,0,45).
>
> In Blender if you look at Buttons Window -> Scene -> Render Buttons ->
>   Format, you can set the render aspect ratio.  Set AspY to half of
>   AspX.  This is the same as taking regular rendered output and scaling
>   X by 50%.  If you rendered a cube, the top of the cube will be a
>   perfect square (though at a 45 degree angle).
>
> We can then use Blender nodes to rotate the result 45 degrees.  The
>   output:
>
> Note this started as a cube, so there's a lot of "vertical"
>   distortion.  So you might have to scale meshes to 50% Z before using
>   this method.  Also notice the Edge seems to be applied after the
>   Aspect, so the edge isn't distorted.
>
> Blend file: http://clintbellanger.net/images/temp/UltimaVII.blend (I'm
>   a Nodes noob so there might be a smarter setup).
>
> For kicks, here is that tower again.  I pulled it into the above
>   workflow scene and scaled Z by 50%.  Click "Re-render this layer" on
>   the first node to create the composite.

On his method, he used stuff like rescaling the render and changing the scale of models, Im convinced I could get along just with the 4x4matrix in unity(or in any other 3d environment really).

Hope someone more experienced with perks of 3D maths could help me to figure it out. Thank you! =D

Answer (score 0):

What you ask for is a simple [parallel projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_projection). The typical orthographic projection is just a special case where the projection rays are perpendicular to the image plane. However, every parallel projection can be represented by an [affine shear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping) followed by a standard orthogonal projection.

> Im convinced I could get along just with the 4x4matrix in unity(or in any other 3d environment really).

Yes. Using default GL conventions here, all you have to do is to take the standard ortho matrix, post-multiply it by an appropriate [shear matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_matrix) and use that as the projection matrix.

Comment: what do you mean by  "an appropriate shear matrix" what exactly I am looking for here?

Comment: Well, you need to define the actual direction of your projection rays, and shear the space in such a way that those rays are transformed to the z axis direction. You probably will also need some translation to keep the image center where you want it to be.

Comment: Can we talk about real matrices here? cause in this level of abstraction I still could find a way to make this work. I got very close but seems to be something off and everything seems a little bit sheer. I am sure its possible because I managed to get the right results on blender.

Comment: "Can we talk about real matrices here?" hardly without having any specific scenario to talk about. Assuming some standard GL eye space, you just want some shear so that `x' = x + a*z` and `y'=y + b*z`. As a result, your matrix will be just (in default GL column major notation): `( (1,0,0,0) , (0,1,0,0), (a,b,1,0), (0,0,0,1) )`. Depending of the actual coordinate conventions you're using, and also where you want the plane of 0 offset want to be, things might also have to look a bit different. From the image in the question, it looks like `a=b` (assuming some aspect-conserving ortho projection).